# USB memory stick not recognised

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

I have a 32Gb USB flash disk that is currently not recognised by my Ubuntu (20.04) system. Up until recently, this drive worked fine under both Ubuntu and Windows. Then I re-partitioned it to use it with gparted (which also worked fine). When I tried to re-format it back to FAT32 it stopped working.

When I insert it into the USB port, I get the following from `dmesg`:

```
[Apr17 14:06] usb 3-2.1: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.289324] usb 3-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=1234, bcdDevice= 0.01
[  +0.000008] usb 3-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000003] usb 3-2.1: Product: Mass Storage Device
[  +0.000003] usb 3-2.1: Manufacturer: Alcor Micro
[  +0.000448] usb-storage 3-2.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0.000188] scsi host12: usb-storage 3-2.1:1.0
[  +1.030740] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk   7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  +0.000478] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[  +0.055143] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

It doesn't show up on the list generated by `fdisk -l`, and `fdisk -l /dev/sdf` fails.

When I run `lsusb` it shows up as:

```
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 058f:1234 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
```

Windows (Windows 10 on a laptop and Windows 7 on a VM) does not recognise it either.

Comment: I'd recommend that you take your Flash drive back to Windows and reformat it as a FAT32 device. I think that would fix the media and portability issue.

Comment: Hello. why not format it to the more common NTFS?

Comment: I'd happily settle for either of those solutions, but whilst Windows acknowledges that a USB device has been plugged in, and loads a mass storage device driver for it, it does not present it in explorer, or in the disk management tool.

Comment: If you can't format it in both Windows and Ubuntu then it's probably dead.

Comment: @Nmath Agreed, but I'd love to know how I'd killed it. It seems like too much of a coincidence that it happened at exactly the same time I tried to reformat it.

Comment: Barring you spending a lot of money to take it to a clean room for an "autopsy", you'll probably never know.  I don't find it to be a coincidence at all. Things tend to break when they are being used, and you were using it. Storage devices don't last forever. They are the most wearable part of any computer. USB flash drives tend to wear out even faster than internal drives due to their exposure to different conditions, humidity, impact, etc.  And sometimes hardware just fails way sooner than expected. Drive failure falls on a "bathtub curve" (look it up)